# Very slow mouse on login screen

Tags: 12.04, login, mouse, login-screen

I have just finished installing Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS 32 bits on my Toshiba Satellite L355D-S7809 laptop. I have performed apt-get update and upgrade and rebooted. The mouse movement on the login screen is *very* slow. After logging in it works fine. How can I troubleshoot it? The mouse is an USB mouse from an extremely generic brand, it works fine on Windows and on Ubuntu other than on login screen.

Comment: I would think all that you need to do is edit the root (user) mouse movement seeing by running the setting manager as root. but not sure!

Comment: @Andrew it seems to have worked. Please add that as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the mouse movement settings for the `root` user, by running the setting manager as root:

```
sudo gnome-control-center
```

The settings on this screen will be saved for the root user only, and be effective before session login after boot, on the user selection screen.

[image]